# Find surface area generated by $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$ about $-1 \le x \le 1$

Tags: integration

> Find surface area generated by $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$ about $-1 \le x \le 1$

So I got $$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{y^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}, \qquad \sqrt{1+f'(x)}=\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}$$

The rest of the answer looks like $$A = \color{blue}2 \int^{1}_{0} 2 \pi \frac{y}{x^{1/3}} dx $$

How did the 2 appear?

$$= 4\pi \int y^{2/3} \color{blue}{\frac{y^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}} dx= -4\pi \int y^{2/3} dy$$

How did they get this $\frac{y^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}}$ removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stated that

$$-\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = \frac{{{y^{1/3}}}}{{{x^{1/3}}}}$$

You have (note you're missing some limits of integration)

$$\eqalign{
  & 4\pi \int {{y^{2/3}}\frac{{{y^{1/3}}}}{{{x^{1/3}}}}dx}  =   \cr 
  &  - 4\pi \int {{y^{2/3}}\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}dx}  =   \cr 
  &  - 4\pi \int {{y^{2/3}}dy}  \cr} $$

Comment: Oh, icic, $dx$ can also be canceled out ...

Comment: @Jiew Well, it's rather an abuse of notation, but in general, it works.